# hide or show tableview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Say I have a switch and a small table view(no scroll) below it. I know if the switch is turned on/off using a `bool switchState` whose value get changed in the action method of the switch:

```
-(IBAction)switchSlide:(id)sender{
    if (toggleSwitch.on == YES) {
        switchState = YES;
    }
    else{ 
        switchState = NO;
    }
}
```

Now what I want is that the table view below it should hide when the `switchState == NO`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Every `UIView` has a property `hidden`:

```
@property(nonatomic, getter=isHidden) BOOL hidden
```

since a `UITableView` is a sublass of `UIView` you can use the methods from a `UIView` too.
So your code just need a little adjustment (assuming you are calling this `IBAction` in a `UITableViewController`):

```
-(IBAction)switchSlide:(id)sender{
    if (toggleSwitch.on == YES) {
        switchState = YES;
        self.tableView.hidden = NO;
    }
    else{ 
        switchState = NO;
        self.tableView.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Solved this via chat and the solution is:
Since you used a `UIViewController`  you have to make a propert for the `UITableView`. synthesize it and connect the  outlet by dragging from the files owner to the `UITableView` in the interface builder. Now you can use the code above.

Comment: I created the tableView from the nib. `self.tableView.hidden = NO;` or yes gives an error basically saying that `tableView` not found in the view controller.

Comment: are you using a `UITableViewController` or just a `UIViewController`?

Comment: `UITableViewController`. After dragging the tableview into the nib and adjusting connections, I used the method: `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to add individual row into the table view.

Comment: every `UITableViewController` has a property `tableView`. Are you sure there is no typo?

Comment: isn't the scope of `tableView` restricted to the method I mentioned in my comment above?

Comment: since the code I posted is using a property (`self.tableView`) it is not restricted to the scope of the message ...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13901/discussion-between-pfitz-and-sahil-chaudhary)